# Confusion about orthogonality for eigenfunctions of separable PDE, where eigenvalues satisfy $\tan \lambda = \lambda$

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

I am having a go at solving the following simple problem:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rllc}
\dfrac{\partial^{2}T}{\partial x^{2}}+\dfrac{\partial^{2}T}{\partial y^{2}} & =0 & \text{in }[0,1]^{2} & {\rm \text{(i)}}\\
T & =0 & \text{on }y=0, & \text{(ii)}\\
T & =f(x) & \text{on }y=1, & \text{(iii)}\\
\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial x} & =0 & \text{on }x=0, & \text{(iv)}\\
-\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial x} & =\dfrac{\partial^{2}T}{\partial x^{2}} & \text{on }x=1. & \text{(v)}
\end{array}\label{eq:thinWall-approx-heatProblemFluid-effectiveBCs}
\end{equation}

Using separation of variables, such that $T(x,y)={\cal X}(x){\cal Y}(y)$, one can use boundary condition (v) to show that the eigenfunctions are $${\cal X}(x)=\cos \lambda_n x$$
where the eigenvalues $\lambda_n$ satisfy
$$\tan \lambda_n = \lambda_n$$

I am aware that, starting with Laplace's equation, one can get $\cal{X}''(x)/\cal{X}(x) = -\lambda^2$, which is expressible in Sturm-Liouville form as

$$(p(x)\cal{X}'(x))'+(q(x)+\mu r(x))\cal{X}(x) = 0$$
where $p(x) = 1$, $q(x)$ = 0, $\mu = \lambda_n ^2$ and $r(x) = 1$, and that the weight function in the orthogonality of eigenfunctions is given by $r(x)$. The set of values $\{\lambda_n\}$ satisfying $\tan\lambda = \lambda$ is increasing, countably infinite, and $\lambda_n \sim \left(n+\tfrac{1}{2} \right)\pi$ as $n\to\infty$. Furthermore $\lim_{n\to\infty}\lambda_n = \infty$, so as far as I can tell this is a standard Sturm-Liouville problem for which orthogonality of the eigenfunctions should hold on the interval $[0,1]$ (with respect to the weight function $r(x) \equiv 1.$)

I am therefore confused about why  I am getting something different to $\text{constant}\times\delta_{mn}$ for the integral $$\int_{0}^{1}\cos \lambda_m x \cos \lambda_n x {\rm d}x=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\lambda_{m}\sin\lambda_{m}\cos\lambda_{n}-\lambda_{n}\cos\lambda_{m}\sin\lambda_{n}}{\left(\lambda_{m}-\lambda_{n}\right)\left(\lambda_{m}+\lambda_{n}\right)}, & m\neq n,\\
\dfrac{2\lambda_{n}+\sin2\lambda_{n}}{4\lambda_{n}}, & m=n.
\end{cases}$$
Obviously this does give $\delta_{mn}/2$ in the case where $\lambda_n = \left(n+\tfrac{1}{2} \right)\pi$, since $\cos\left(n+\tfrac{1}{2} \right)\pi = 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb {Z}$, and I can make headway by using $\tan \lambda_n = \lambda_n$ to show that

$$\frac{\lambda_{m}\sin\lambda_{m}\cos\lambda_{n}-\lambda_{n}\cos\lambda_{m}\sin\lambda_{n}}{\left(\lambda_{m}-\lambda_{n}\right)\left(\lambda_{m}+\lambda_{n}\right)} = \cos\lambda_{n}\cos\lambda_{m}. $$

but if I make a small perturbation around these roots, say, $\varepsilon_n = \lambda_n - \left(n+\tfrac{1}{2} \right)\pi$, I can show that

$$ \int_{0}^{1}\cos\lambda_{n}x\cos\lambda_{m}x{\rm d} x=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{2}(-1)^{m+n}\varepsilon_{m}\varepsilon_{n}+{\cal O}(\varepsilon_{m}\varepsilon_{n}^{2}), & m\neq n,\\
\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{\varepsilon_{n}^{2}}{2}+{\cal O}(\varepsilon_{n}^{4}) & m=n.
\end{cases}.$$

I can clearly see that the result will converge to $\delta_{mn}/2$ as $m,n\to\infty$ so that $\varepsilon_m,\varepsilon_n \to 0$, but I am still confused as to why the integral is not giving **exactly** $\delta_{mn}/2$ given that it seems to resemble a standard Sturm-Liouville problem. I am therefore in a situation where I cannot uniquely determine the coefficients in the usual series expansion.

My questions are as follows:

1. *Does the fact that my inner product does not equal $\delta_{mn}/2$ exactly mean that I have used the wrong weight function? If so, how can I find a suitable one to use?*
2. *Is there another subtlety in this problem that I have missed?*

Comment: Is (v) not better stated as a Robin boundary condition $T+\partial_x T = \text{const}$?

Comment: It can, but it comes from an effective boundary condition at a thin wall (here $T$ denotes temperature inside a fluid domain, but at $x=a$ it would be equal to the value of the temperature in the solid, $T_{\rm s}$, which has been eliminated from the problem).

Rewriting that boundary condition as you suggest has no effect on the series solution for $T(x,y)$, but it still doesn't circumvent the issue I have with the orthogonality. Do correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: In either case, $\cos \lambda_n x$ is still the eigenfunction for ${\cal X}(x)$; if a constant is introduced into boundary condition (v) then it just means that ${\cal X}(x)$ is a multiple of $\cos \lambda_n x$ where the coefficient involves $\lambda$. That can be absorbed inside the coefficients ${\cal C}_n$ in the series expansion.

Comment: Your (v) doesn't really make any sense mathematically speaking. Viewing it as a Robin condition is the mathematically correct perspective. But yes, the change is inconsequential from the point of view of the separation of variables solution.

Comment: Could you please clarify why it doesn't make any mathematical sense?

Comment: You generally can't impose boundary conditions of the same order as the differential equation. There are a lot of reasons for this, but it is easiest to see in the context of ODE IVPs, in which case we view everything as first order equations on some phase space (that might be higher dimensional than the space the variables live in).

Comment: Here's another one for you: is it possible to prove in this instance that $\int_{0}^{a}\sin\lambda_{n}x\cos\lambda_{m}x{\rm d} x=0$ and $\int_{0}^{a}\sin\lambda_{n}x\sin\lambda_{m}x{\rm d} x=0$? Do these hold regardless of the eigenvalues as long as they satisfy the Sturm-Liouville properties, or only when $\lambda_n = n\pi x/a$ or $(n+\tfrac{1}{2})\pi x/a$?

Comment: @epsilonD3LT4 Unless they're actually the eigenfunctions of some problem, you shouldn't expect them to be orthogonal. Being the eigenfunctions depends on both what the frequencies are and which kind of trig function you're talking about.

Comment: If this problem were to be reflected through the y-axis, the Robin condition would become $T_x - T = c$ at $x = -1$ and this would replace the symmetry condition at $x = 0$. In this instance both cosine and sine would be eigenfunctions for the problem. The problem in the half-space is an attempt to make things easier to deal with by assuming that $T$ is a function of $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it is more likely that the correct form of the last boundary condition problem is $T+T_x=c$, which you homogenize (i.e. set $c=0$) for purposes of determining the associated eigenfunctions. This form is needed to check self-adjointness, which is done as follows:

$$\int_0^1 u v'' dx = u(1) v'(1) - u(0) v'(0) - \int_0^1 u' v' dx \\= u(1) v'(1) - u(0) v'(0) - u'(1) v(1) + u'(0) v(0) + \int_0^1 u'' v dx$$

Now the terms at $x=0$ are just zero while the terms at $x=1$ cancel because $u(1) v'(1) - u'(1) v(1)=-u(1) v(1) + u(1) v(1)=0$.

To see why this is correct physically you have to notice that actually $T_x(1)$ is the current of heat into the domain, so that should be like $c-T$. The second derivative in the heat equation comes from what is left over after the current through the left side of a small region is cancelled by the current through the right side.

Second, the resulting problem has a nontrivial solution if $\left. \frac{\partial }{\partial x} \cos(\lambda x) \right |_{x=1} + \cos(\lambda)=0$ i.e. $-\lambda \sin(\lambda)+\cos(\lambda)=0$ i.e. $\lambda=\cot(\lambda)$ not $\lambda=\tan(\lambda)$. In this case in the numerator of your expression for $m \neq n$, you have

$$\cot(\lambda_m) \sin(\lambda_m) \cos(\lambda_n) - \cot(\lambda_n) \sin(\lambda_n) \cos(\lambda_m) \\ 
=\cos(\lambda_m) \cos(\lambda_n) - \cos(\lambda_n) \cos(\lambda_m) \\
=0.$$

Now for the modeling question. Consider 1D for simplicity. Suppose you have a Dirichlet condition at $0$ where $T=T_1$, a Dirichlet condition at $1+h$ where $T=T_2$, and different conductivities $K_1,K_2$ in $(0,1)$ and $(1,1+h)$. This amounts to

$$T''=0 \quad x \neq 1 \\
T(0)=T_1 \\
T(1+h)=T_2.$$

Because there is nowhere outside the system for energy to go, in order to have conservation of energy we must match fluxes at the interface:

$$K_1 T'(1^-)=K_2 T'(1^+).$$

The question then is what actually is $T'(1^-)$? You need an additional boundary condition to say. The conventional answer is to use a Robin condition so that the flux through the interface is proportional to the jump in the temperature. Thus you set it up with

$$K_1 T'(1^-)=K_1 a_1 \\
= K_3(T(1^+)-T(1^-)) \\
= K_3(-a_1-a_2 h + T_2 - T_1) \\
= K_2 a_2.$$

In general this conductivity $K_3$ is not the same as either $K_1$ or $K_2$.

So you read off the equation for $a_1$:

$$K_1 a_1=K_3 \left ( -a_1 - \frac{K_1}{K_2} a_1 h + T_2 - T_1 \right )$$

from which you recover $a_1=\frac{T_2-T_1}{1+\frac{K_1}{K_3}+\frac{K_1 h}{K_2}}$.

Comment: Is the intuition for expressing boundary condition (v) as Robin *so that* self-adjointedness can be checked, since all the derivatives in (v) are then of lower order than those that appear in the PDE?

It makes sense that re-expressing boundary condition (v) in the form that you have said works, and I can see that it resembles the result of integrating boundary condition (v) with respect to $x$ as though it were an equation. I didn't think this was mathematically justified, given that the "integration" would be taking place in a direction normal to the boundary at $x = 1$?

Comment: Boundary condition (v) actually comes from a thin-wall approximation of the boundary condition $\frac{\partial T}{\partial x} = K \frac{\partial T_{\rm s}}{\partial x}$ where $T_{\rm s}$ is the temperature in the solid wall (assumed to be thin).

Comment: @epsilonD3LT4 Physically what you have written down doesn't actually make sense either because the second derivative doesn't physically mean anything at the boundary. What you want to do is to define the flux through the interface. This flux, as an inward flux, is proportional to $\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}$. You chose to set this equal to the outward flux from the solid.

Comment: @epsilonD3LT4 (Cont.) What is that outward flux going to be? Determining it requires solving another static heat equation in the solid. This needs boundary conditions: flux matching (which demands continuity at the interface to avoid infinite fluxes!) and you have to say something about the boundary condition on the right side of the solid. You cannot just "pretend the wall is thin" and go from there, no matter how thin it is.

Comment: @epsilonD3LT4 I wrote a little bit about modeling of this thin wall scenario.

Comment: @epsilonD3LT4 Ignore what I said two comments back about infinite fluxes, that was wrong.